# $.ajax() response handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to check my response of an ajax query but I can't seem to figure out how to parse the results.

```
$('input[name=sendpassword]').click(function(){
                var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
                var dataString = "uid=" + uid + "&password=" + password;
                console.log(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/assets/inc/check-password.php",
                    data:dataString,
                    dataType:'html',
                    context:document.body,
                    global:false,
                    async:false,
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data[0].id==true){
                            console.log("success");
                        } else {
                            console.log("failed");
                        }
                        //window.location.replace(reffer);
                        //document.location ="/";
                    }
                });
            });
```

The console.log shows **{"id":false}** or **{"id":true}** but I'd like to do an if statement with the result

Comment: `dataType:'html'` needs to be `dataType:'json'` if you're getting JSON back.

Comment: lose the `[0]` in `data[0].id`, data is an object not an array

Comment: @red-X the answer box is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this  if (data.d==true)

```
$('input[name=sendpassword]').click(function(){
                var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
                var dataString = "uid=" + uid + "&password=" + password;
                console.log(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/assets/inc/check-password.php",
                    data:dataString,
                    dataType:'json',
                    context:document.body,
                    global:false,
                    async:false,
                    success:function(data){
                    console.log(data.d);
                        if (data.d==true){
                            console.log("success");
                        } else {
                            console.log("failed");
                        }
                        //window.location.replace(reffer);
                        //document.location ="/";
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `jQuery.parseJSON( data )` and instead of `if (data[0].id==true){` use `if (data.id=="true"){`

```
$('input[name=sendpassword]').click(function(){
                var password = $("input[name=password]").val();
                var dataString = "uid=" + uid + "&password=" + password;
                console.log(dataString);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/assets/inc/check-password.php",
                    data:dataString,
                    dataType:'html',
                    context:document.body,
                    global:false,
                    async:false,
                    success:function(data){
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.id==true){
                            console.log("success");
                        } else {
                            console.log("failed");
                        }
                        //window.location.replace(reffer);
                        //document.location ="/";
                    }
                });
            });
```

OR as suggested by `Jared`

> dataType:'html' needs to be dataType:'json'.

then you wouldn't need to parse into JSON

Comment: Wouldn't changing the `dataType` to `json` be more straight-forward?

Answer (score 0):

If the console just shows `{"id":false}` (i.e. not showing an array) then you can use it via: `data.id==true`

Comment: The quotes around the `id` lead me to believe it's not already been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the result first, so you can access the individual components within the result.

```
var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(data)
```

Then access like `parsedResponse.id`, which you can use inside your `if` condition.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, :) fixed that.